# When i run a netbeans project the content in the window doesn't open until i hit maximize

Tags: java, netbeans

i have only started using Netbeans and i'm pretty inexperience. When i hit the green play button (to run the project). The window opens, but the content doesn't until i re size it myself. This only happens when i have a background image in the projected and the layout is set till null.
It opens like this

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Did you pack the frame to it's contents?

```
frame.pack();
```

Comment: I used the drag and drop GUI builder on Netbeans, so were should i put this ?

Comment: I personally don't use that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the frame size is not set to 0. In Netbeans this is on the properties tab on the right. There is minimum size, preferred size and maximum size. Check that none of these have X and Y coordinates of 0